# R emmeans analysis not working, crazy values and graph

Tags: r, graph, emmeans

I'm analyzing a dataset with my y-value being protein levels ranging from 0-3.6nmol/L. I did a sqrt transformation of a linear model and am trying to do a post-hoc test, but my emmean values and confidence intervals don't make sense, especially because one of the means somehow came out to be negative.

I initialized my model like this:

```
fasting.sqrt <- lm(sqrt(FCP) ~ Type * BMI_Percentile, data = Database_Mexican_children_with_different_types_of_DM)
```

then made my dataframe for posthoc looking specifically at Type:

```
fasting.sqrt.emm = emmeans(fasting.sqrt, specs="Type") %>% as.data.frame()
```

which returned this:

```
# Type  emmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
#  1     0.732 0.0980 129    0.538    0.926
#  2    -0.391 0.6511 129   -1.679    0.897
#  3     0.708 0.0728 129    0.564    0.852
#  4     0.260 0.8955 129   -1.512    2.032
```

and, using this graphing code:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=Database_Mexican_children_with_different_types_of_DM, aes(x=Type, y=FCP), alpha=0.3) +
  geom_errorbar(data=fasting.sqrt.emm, aes(x=Type, ymin=lower.CL*abs(lower.CL), ymax=(upper.CL)^2), width=0.1) +
  geom_point(data=fasting.sqrt.emm, aes(x=Type, y=emmean*abs(emmean)), 
             color="red", size=3) +
  theme_classic()
```

I used the `abs()` to account for negative values, because squaring would place lower confidence levels incorrectly

I got this graph:

[image]

The means should all be around positive 0.7-2ish, with confidence intervals from around 0 to 1-3ish.

Answer (score 5):

Although the outcome values that you supplied to `lm()` were necessarily non-negative, there is nothing that forces the *outcome predictions* from the model to be non-negative. What `emmeans()` reports is a type of prediction from the `lm()` model. You can't just ignore the fact that the `emmean` for `Type 2` is negative and arbitrarily take absolute values of what it provides.

Your plot of raw values *ignores* the model's interaction between `Type` and what seems to be a continuous `BMI_Percentile` predictor. With that interaction, the association between outcome and `Type` *depends on* the value of `BMI_Percentile`. The `emmeans` predictions that you overlie on the raw data are *estimated marginal means* based on the entire model with that interaction, and evaluated (by default) at the mean value of `BMI_Percentile`. That's not necessarily a very useful comparison in an observational study with unbalanced data, as this seems to be.

Your invocation of `emmeans()` hides a lot of what might be important in your model with its interaction term. You would probably be better off using the `emtrends()` function of the package to display results over a range of `BMI_Percentile` values. The help page seems to describe your situation:

> The `emtrends` function is useful when a fitted model involves a numerical predictor x interacting with another predictor a (typically a factor).